# Tempo de checagem de branch GIT e jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

Criei uma integração entre o GIT e o Jenkins para que as builds sejam executadas com parâmetros de publicação nos servidores de aplicações.

Então configurei o GIT plugin o caminho do projeto e em *Branch Specifier (blank for 'any')* a branch `master` e em 'Consultar Periodicamente o SCM' configurei par fazer a verificação de alterações de um em um minuto.

Existe uma maneira de fazer com que as builds sejam geradas apenas com alterações do projeto GIT, ou seja, quando o dev alterar e commitar? E, assim, retirar essa checagem de branch do SCM de minuto em minuto?

Answer (score 0):

você pode configurar webhook do seu servidor de git para que a cada push seja disparado para seu jenkins uma requisição para ele poder executar a tarefa,detalhe se estiver usando seu jenkins localhost tem que usar algum mecanismo para expor seu ip para poder receber a requisição do webhook através de um tunnel  no caso eu utilizei https://ngrok.com/